# Bootstrap4: После добавления подвала появляется линия с фоном

Tags: html, bootstrap4

я делаю сайт, начал делать подвал, вроде сдедал. Проверил, вроде выглядит нормально.
Начал проверять мобильную версию, и обнаружил артефакт, вот он
[image: скрин]

При удалении подвала, эта линия пропадает, и сразу ясно что дело в подвале.

Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот код footer.php:

```
<footer class="footer-bg">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <h3 class="text-light">Меню</h3>
                <ul class="list-unstyled three-column">
                    <li><a href="/" title="Нажми">Главная</a></li>
                    <?
                    if($user->ifLogged()){
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="/my-account" title="Нажми">Профиль</a></li>
                    <?
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li><a href="/product" title="Нажми">Аккаунты</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/page/ofera" title="Нажми">Офера</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/page/contacts" title="Нажми">Контакты</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/page/info-for-shop" title="Нажми">О магазине</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
<footer2>
    <div class="row bg-dark">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul class="socila-list-copy">
                <h6 class="text-light">Мы в соц.сетях</h6>
                <li><a href="https://vk.com/*вк" title="Ссылка на группу в вк"><i class="fa fa-vk fa-2x"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/*канал" title="Ссылка на YouTube канал"><i class="fa fa-youtube fa-2x"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright col-md-6 text-center bg-dark text-light">
            <p>Copyright &copy; <? echo date("Y"); ?> <a href="<? echo $siteurl; ?>" title="CookieShop">название</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</footer2>
```

Код footer.css:

```
footer
{
    /*background : #222;*/
    
    color : #aaa;
    padding-top : 10px;
}

.footer-bg{
    background: url('../images/footer-bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}

footer a
{
    color : white;
}

footer a:hover
{
    color : rgba(255 255 255 / 0.2);
}

footer h3
{
    /*color : #0894d1;*/
    letter-spacing : 1px;
    margin : 30px 0 20px;
}

footer .three-column
{
    overflow : hidden;
}

footer .three-column li
{
    width : 33.3333%;
    float : left;
    padding : 5px 0;
}

/*footer .socila-list
{
    overflow : hidden;
    margin : 20px 0 10px;
}


footer .socila-list li
{
    float : left;
    margin-right : 3px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow : hidden;
    border-radius : 50%;
    transition : all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

footer .socila-list li:hover
{
    opacity : 1;
}*/

footer2{
    height: 120px;
}

footer2 .socila-list-copy
{
    overflow : hidden;
    margin : 20px 0 10px;
}


footer2 .socila-list-copy li
{
    float : left;
    margin-right : 3px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    overflow : hidden;
    border-radius : 50%;
    transition : all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

footer2 .socila-list-copy li a{
    color: white;
}

footer2 .socila-list-copy li:hover
{
    opacity : 1;
}

footer2 .copyright
{
    padding : 15px 0;
    background : #333;
    margin-top : 20px;
    font-size : 15px;
}

footer2 .copyright span
{
    color : #0894d1;
}
footer2 .copyright a
{
    color : #FED700;
}
```

Надеюсь я кого нибудь заинтересовал
Жду...

Comment: Можно ссылку на сайт?

Comment: Это demo домен, и хостинг бесплатный. Потом закончу перейду на платный. Вот сайт http://cookieshop.rf.gd

Comment: Так как дизайнера у меня в друзьях нет, выкручиваюсь сам. Но заказчику вроде нравиться.

Answer (score 0):

В блока `footer2` у `div.row` есть bootstrap-стиль `margin-right` и `margin-left` -15px. Они нужны для правильного сочитания с контейнером.

Решение вашей проблемы:

1. Добавьте к `footer2` класс `container`
2. Тега `footer2` не существует. Либо замените на `footer`, либо на `div`, либо **в крайнем случае** добавьте ему стиль `display: block`

Comment: Я сделал как вы написали. После добавления класса container к footer он в версии пк не на всю ширину становится, а линия прополает.

Comment: Я к footer2.row добавил класс container, и к footer2, footer2.row добавил класс bg-dark, также я заменил footer2 на footer. И вроде линия пропала. Но появился пустой прямоугольник в правом нижнем углу.

Comment: @Develop, тогда `footer2` добавьте `container-fluid` вместо `container`. Добавлять клас containter к row - не очень хорошо.